# Relationships between several tables in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration, relationship

I have three services on the site
And when the user orders one of the services. That order is stored in its own table
So we have three tables to store the order information of each service

```
table order
 -id
 -And shared information such as amount or number

table Service1_Order
 -id
 - and Specific fields of this service

table Service2_Order
 -id
 - and Specific fields of this service

table Service3_Order
 -id
 - and Specific fields of this service
```

Now when we want to show all the orders to the user, we can not bring them to one page. We have to create a new order page for each service, but this is a mistake. How can we display all orders in one page and one table  (since each service has its own information) What relationships should there be between tables?

Answer (score 1):

The details of your problem is not clear but as i understand from your text you can achieve that goal with polymorphic relationships and you don't need to make table for each service.

learn more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships)